# The dynamically allocated array of chars that i'm trying to create is not working good

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

I'm trying to create a program that asks for a letter and creates a dynamical array of the amount passed by the user, but i'm having some trouble since the array i am creating is always giving me no length. What am i doing wrong?

PD: The code is not finished, i want to know my error before cotinuing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK 0
#define ERROR -1

int pedir_memoria(char **arreglo, int cant_letras);
int cargar_letra(char letra,char**arreglo,int cant_letras);

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

  char *arreglo = NULL;
  char letra;
  int cant_letras = 0, estado,largo;

  do 
  {
    printf("ingrese letras: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letra);
    
    cant_letras++;
  
    estado = pedir_memoria(&arreglo, cant_letras);

    if(estado != ERROR)
    printf("memoria solicitada correctmanete \n");

    // estado = cargar_letra(letra,&arreglo,cant_letras);
 
  } 
  while (letra > 'A' && letra < 'z');

  largo = strlen(arreglo);

  printf("arr length: %d \n",largo);

  return 0;
}

int pedir_memoria(char **arreglo, int cant_letras) 
{

  int estado = ERROR;
  char *aux = NULL;
  
  if (arreglo != NULL && cant_letras != 0) 
  {
    if(cant_letras == 1) 
    {
      (*arreglo) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * cant_letras);

      if (*arreglo != NULL) 
      estado = OK;
      
    } 
    else 
    {
      aux = (char*)realloc(*arreglo,sizeof(char) * cant_letras);
        
      if(aux != NULL)
      {
        *arreglo = aux;  
        estado = OK;
      } 
    }
  }

  return estado;
}


int cargar_letras(char letra,char**arreglo,int cant_letras)
{
    int estado;

    if(arreglo != NULL && cant_letras != 0)
    {
        (*(arreglo[cant_letras - 1])) = letra;
        estado = OK;
    }

    return estado;
}
```

i tried to directly use a big malloc with a magic number instead of giving the amount of characters and to print the length of the array from the function itself and is still throwing me the cero value.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is littering because it's 1 by the standard.

Comment: Could you be more specific what issue you have, expectations and actual result.

Comment: Aside: `realloc( NULL, n );` works just like `malloc( n );`... There's no need to treat the first letter differently from all the subsequent letters being added.

Comment: @elmarti, When `A` is entered, what should  `while (letra > 'A' && letra < 'z');` do?

Comment: So basically i want do ask for letters until the user writes something that is not. Each char must be put into the dynamically created array. Then i will print the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from the strlen fnc, the function counts till it finds a '\0' in your string. When you malloc the array is set to random values, so it can't find when it ends. The better way to print the length of your array would be to use directly cant_letras.